# what is the correct way to use Sass and React JS?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have a question. I´m Learning how to use React JS 18v. My question is: what is the best way to use Sass with React? how do you compile it? I don't want to use an extension of VSC to compile.

I will be greatfull if someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using sass for quite some time, and learned that the best way to compile and use it is to turn it into css beforehand: use `Koala compiler`. Koala is super easy to use and will compile your sass into css lighting fast. Afterwards, just use the css file as normal :D

Comment: I was checking and the last version was 2017 so I don´t know if supports modern sass

Comment: yup, it suppots everything, I've used it this morning

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use Styled Components instead pure Sass. It's a react library using Sass syntax out there, but the most value is, that you can pass the props to render styles conditionally, that makes it super useful.
https://styled-components.com/docs/basics

Comment: mmm insteresting, I´m a completly noob. But I will check it out in the future :)

Comment: It's quite easy, if you know how to use components in React and how to use CSS generally, you will know how those two are combine in Styled Components as well :)